# Connecting with MongoDB in Javascript without NodeJs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have an UI5 Application [Mobile-Fiori], and I would like to connect it with MongoDB to get JSON data to be displayed in my views.

I know it would have been possible if I used Node.js with the package [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/), but for my applications developed locally, I use Eclipse with Tomcat Server.

I wonder if this is possible in this way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, e.g. with [Spring Data MongoDB](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/).

Comment: Excuse me but i am talking about Javascript Application, SapUI5 is an JS Framework, and Spring is for Java Development.

Comment: Where's the point. Your question was how to expose data from MongoDB to a UI5 application which is published on a Tomcat server. One solution would be to use Spring Data MongoDB. UI5 neither connects directly to a MongoDB nor does it care about the programming language of your backend. Normally it uses HTTP calls to obtain data. Please consider to clarify the question.

Comment: So How can i implement this solution?

Comment: This is a completely wrong answer. OP asks for a solution in Javascript, but the answer is provided for JAVA.

Comment: The question refers to Tomcat which (normally) runs Java based applications, so where is your point?